# How do I restart Pokemon Go?

Tags: pokemon-go

I am on level 3 and I want reset my progress, how do I do it? I have tried to delete my Google account and make a new one.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is any way to reset your progress.  You can, however, create a new account with a different email address to start over.